# Oracle DB: calculate age from strings

Tags: oracle

I need to calculate age for the people and their birthdates are saved in `varchar2` like `19900130`, and some people don't have their birthdates recorded and default value is `00000000`.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    e.id_number,
    e.birth_dt,
    (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(e.birth_dt, 1, 4) = '0000' THEN 0
          WHEN SUBSTR(e.birth_dt, 1, 4) <> '0000' THEN
              ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(e.birth_dt, 'YYYYMMDD')) / 12) 
          ELSE -1
     END) age
FROM employee e
```

The error is:

> ORA-01843: Not a valid month

Is anything wrong? I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Can you share some sample data from the `birth_dt` column?  If you have bad data, or the format mask be wrong, this could explain the error.

Comment: I think you are right. I tried this on some group of people, it worked! but if applied to all people,error came out. maybe that's reason you said. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you can come up with a query to detect which rows have invalid date data.

Comment: yes i will.........just found some invalid type ..some missing month and date

Comment: You found one of the many reasons to store dates in the DATE data type. If the dates come in as strings, they should be inspected, flagged if they don't represent valid dates, and the rest should be converted to dates. You can store the strings in a column (for auditing purposes) but never use that column in any queries - use the DATE column you create and you populate with the dates from converting valid strings.

Comment: Also: This has nothing to do with PL/SQL, so I will edit the tabs and the title.

Answer (score 0):

Is anything wrong? Yes, your case is not covering the possibility that some strings have something other than 01, 02, ..., 12 in character positions 5 and 6. Likewise, your case is not covering the possibility that the day of the month character positions are something other than 01, 02, ... 31 (and the covering of the possibility that a day of the month is not valid for a particular month).

If I were you, I'd add a proper date column, modify the app to populate both columns, fix the app so that it stops putting bad data into the table, decide what to do with the bad data, modify the app to stop populating the varchar2 column, and then drop the varchar2 column.